# Function is undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to use a timer in my javascript to poll certain data every 5seconds from my other objects in cshtml and update it into the function in javascript.

i have explored with the following code but it seems to throw the error of initialize is undefined

```
function initialize() {

    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
        zoom: parseInt(5),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
        , mapProp);


}

$(document).ready(function () {
    initialize();
});
window.setInterval(function () {
    /// call your function here
    initialize();
}, 5000);
```

However, this works perfectly fine

```
function initialize() {

    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
        zoom: parseInt(5),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
        , mapProp);


}

$(document).ready(function () {
    initialize();
});
```

As i want to make the variables global such that i can update the focus on the map every 5 seconds, i have tried to make it a global variable

```
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
        zoom: parseInt(5),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
```

However, it seems that the script keeps on giving me an error of google is undefined.

Is there anyway i could resolve my problem.

For example i would like to update the parameters in new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850) every 5 seconds.

Comment: If you use the `var` keyword inside a function then it's *not* a global variable, it's scoped to that function.

Comment: There is nothing global with var - it sets the local variable - global variable is typed **without var** or explicitly as a window property => `window.myVariable = "something";`

Comment: Have you included the script?

Comment: What about writing the setInterval function inside document ready ?

Comment: if ur getting google is undefined check whether google api ur using is correct i.e the script(google) ur using in the page

Comment: @jigar i have just tried and it still throws a initialize is undefined

Comment: What is the version of google map api you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var mapProp;
            $(document).ready(function(){initialize();})
            function initialize()
            {
                mapProp = changeMapProp();
                var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
                ,mapProp);
            }
            function changeMapProp() {
                mapProp = {
                    center:new google.maps.LatLng(52.508742,-0.120850),
                    zoom:5,
                    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                return mapProp;
            }
            window.setInterval(function () {
                /// call your function here
                initialize();
            }, 5000);

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var mapProp;
var map;

var initialize = function() {

    mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
        zoom: parseInt(5),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
        , mapProp);

}

$(document).ready(function () {

    setTimeout(initialize, 5000);

});
```

Comment: the debugger shows the error at initialize in the window.setinterval function

Answer (score 1):

You can't make `var mapProp` global because it will fire the `center: new google.maps...` straight away, and your `google` variable won't be in place yet (which is why you get google undefined).

Regarding the initialize undefined, put your `setInterval` inside your `$(document).ready` function.